# Issue with stopping ball animation after game ends

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

For my basic pong game that I am programming, I am working on the end game (not Avengers) effects. I have made a button saying play again, and I am trying to make the command so that when I press the button, the ball pos.x and the ball pos.y will "reset" to the middle of the screen, and then continue moving.

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10,10,25,25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False


    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False


    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3



class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>',self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)


    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0


    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self. x = -3


    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 3


tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')



def Restart():
    #This is where the code for restart was, but it failed so...



button = Button(tk, text="Play Again", command=Restart)
button.config(height=3, width= 15, fg='white', bg='#28fc03', activebackground='#28fc03')
canvas.configure(bg='black')


while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == True:
        Restart()
        button.place(x=195, y=125)
    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

The only problem is, that when I make a reset function to move the ball to the middle, I also have a 'while 1' loop running at the bottom, and I think that has something to do with the fact that no matter what I try to do, the ball will not reset, and will just stay on the bottom of the screen. I have not yet made code for the PLAY AGAIN button to disappear, but that is not that difficult, and I will do so shortly.

Simply explained, is there a way to *stop* the ball.draw() and the paddle.draw() loop?

Comment: Thanks @TheLazyScripter I will look into it

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Where am I not setting the ball.hit_bottom to be True?

Comment: I was incorrect and happened to miss your set

Comment: So would you happen to know where I am going wrong? You might have already answered, but I am not of the most intelligent human beings.

Comment: By the way, if anyone provide can even a decently good solution to my problem, I will mark it as accepted, because any help is greatly appreciated and I need an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing, i found that your `Restart` IS working,but repeatly runs,so it DOES working,but maybe your program in `def restart` are with some wrong.

for guessing, i think you forgot to set ball.hit_bottom back to false.

after some minutes,i fix it in another way, i think with that, you can make it into the stuffs you want,cause i am confused.

```
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10,10,25,25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False


    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False


    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3
#here's the part i added
    def place(self,x,y):
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]#confuse
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3


class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>',self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)


    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0


    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self. x = -3


    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 3


tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')



def Restart():# i changed some stuff for testing,but it manages to work a bit
    print(1)
    ball.place(0,0)
    ball.hit_bottom = False
    #This is where the code for restart was, but it failed so...



button = Button(tk, text="Play Again", command=Restart)
button.config(height=3, width= 15, fg='white', bg='#28fc03', activebackground='#28fc03')
canvas.configure(bg='black')

while 1:

    if ball.hit_bottom == True:
        button.place(x=195, y=125)

        #Restart() #try with that?
    elif ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: This worked! I just have to make a few edits, but thanks for the help!

Comment: The starts is just a variable with a list, and I use the shuffle module to randomly pick one of those numbers for the ball to go in that direction.